# How to write data entry in html form to .csv file on server?

Tags: php, forms, export-to-csv

I have a phpform which sends data to my email. On this forum i saw somebody posted following code which can write data to a csv file.

```
 <?php
 $fieldA = $_POST["textnames"];
 $fieldB = $_POST["fathername"];
 $fieldC = $_POST["paddress"];
 $fieldD = $_POST["personaladdress"];
 $fieldE = $_POST["sex"];
 $fieldF = $_POST["Stream"];
 $fieldG = $_POST["Core-1"];
 $fieldH = $_POST["Core-2"];
 $fieldI = $_POST["Elective-1"];
 $fieldJ = $_POST["Elective-2"];
 $fieldK = $_POST["Elective-3"];
 $fieldL = $_POST["Elective-4"];
 $fieldM = $_POST["Compulsory"];

 $keys = array($fieldA,$fieldB,$fieldC,$fieldD,$fieldE,$fieldF,$fieldG,$fieldH,$fieldI,$fieldJ,$fieldK,$fieldL,$fieldM); //THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT THE FORM ELEMENTS ex: array('$fieldA','$fieldB',etc)
 $csv_line = $keys;
 foreach( $keys as $key ){
     array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);

 }
 $fname = 'data.csv'; //NAME OF THE FILE
 $csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
 if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = $csv_line."\r\n" ;}
 $fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
 $fcontent = $csv_line;
 fwrite($fcon,$csv_line);
 fclose($fcon);
 ?>
```

Pls help with some doubts. Where do i place the data.csv file, i mean in any specific folder or root folder? Should i place a blank csv file or i need to place any code in the columns?

EDIT:

How do i connect this php to my form. Currently the form is connected to php file which uses phpmailer to send text data and attachment files to my mail. In addition i want the text data to be written in the csv file on server.

Comment: `Where do i place the data.csv file`...wherever you want it. It's up to you. There are no rules (unless you have other constraints which you haven't mentioned here).

Comment: `Should i place a blank csv file` you shouldn't need to place any file, if it doesn't exist then your code can create it the first time.

Comment: P.S. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php . Don't re-invent the wheel.